# Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

ProductDetail Model:

```
 public function getProduct(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Products');
}
```

Product model:

```
    public function detail(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductDetails');
}
```

homepage blade:

```
            @foreach ($product_slider as $index=>$product_details)
                <div class="ps-banner"><img class="mobile-only" src="{{asset('farmart/')}}/img/slider/home-1/slide_03_mobile.png" alt="alt"><img class="desktop-only" src="{{asset('farmart/')}}/img/slider/home-1/slide_03.png" alt="alt">
                    <div class="ps-content {{ $index==0 ? 'active':'' }}">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="ps-content-box">
                                <div class="ps-node"><span class='text-danger'>SALE UP TO 30%</span></div>
                                <div class="ps-title">{{ $product_details->getProduct->product_name}}</div>
                                <div class="ps-subtitle">Only from <br><span class='price'>{{ $product_details->getProduct->price }} TL</span></div>
                                <div class="ps-shopnow"> <a href="shop-view-grid.html">Shop Now<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

HomeController :

```
       $product_slider=ProductDetails::with('getProduct')->where('show_slider', 1)->take(3)->get();

    return view('homepage' ,compact('product_slider'));
```

error-->Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Comment: Is your Model  namespace `'App\Models\Products'` or `'App\Models\Product'` ? The `s` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

productDetails model:

```
    public function getProduct(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Products','products_id');
}
```

fix as above

Comment: A little explanation of _what_ you changed and _why_ this would solve OPs problem would be helpful

Comment: Please explain a bit. Thanks

Comment: Because if the products and the function name are the same, Laravel automatically takes a foreign key column. Here, the function name is different, either use product instead of getProducts or foreign key column should specify products_id.

Answer (score 0):

your getting this error because in `$product_details->getProduct->product_name`  here `getProduct` is undefined

so it will be `$product_details->undefined->product_name` so here you cannot get `product_name` of `undefined`

### solution 1 : -

you can skip the `$product_slider` which doesnot have `$product_details`

```php
@foreach ($product_slider as $index=>$product_details)

  @if (!$product_details->getProduct)
      @continue
  @endif

    <div class="ps-banner"><img class="mobile-only" src="{{asset('farmart/')}}/img/slider/home-1/slide_03_mobile.png" alt="alt"><img class="desktop-only" src="{{asset('farmart/')}}/img/slider/home-1/slide_03.png" alt="alt">
        <div class="ps-content {{ $index==0 ? 'active':'' }}">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="ps-content-box">
                    <div class="ps-node"><span class='text-danger'>SALE UP TO 30%</span></div>
                    <div class="ps-title">{{ $product_details->getProduct->product_name}}</div>
                    <div class="ps-subtitle">Only from <br><span class='price'>{{ $product_details->getProduct->price }} TL</span></div>
                    <div class="ps-shopnow"> <a href="shop-view-grid.html">Shop Now<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

---

### Solution 2 : -

incontroller only retrun those which have `products`

```php
$product_slider=ProductDetails::has('getProduct')->with('getProduct')->where('show_slider', 1)->take(3)->get();

return view('homepage' ,compact('product_slider'));
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence